# Удалить метаданные из документов Microsoft Office

Tags: .net, vba

Нужно средство для массового удаления персональных данных (Автор, 
Организация, Руководитель, и.т.д.) из документов Microsoft Word/Excel/etc

Какие есть средства для этого?

Какие есть готовые решения с возможностью работы из коммандной строки?

Какие можете порекомендовать модули/либы для этого?

Платформа/язык значения не имеют.

Comment: Маленький совет: если для вас платформа/язык не имеют значение, то `C++` (`C#` - не знаю) тут явно лишние. Вместо них укажите таг `Perl`, `Powershell`. Также укажите, установлен ли у вас `Cygwin` или что-то подобное, в таком случае тэг `Cygwin/Bash/Gow/...` не помешает. Если есть Линух - вообще таг `Linux`. Это мое личное мнение, не воспринимайте как коммент от модератора.

Comment: @theoden: а как вы из шелла будете обрабатывать документы [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я высказался чисто исходя из своих догадок. Эти данные можно достать утилитой. Оной же скорее всего можно и отредактировать их. С++ при таких обстаятельствах выглядит как стрельба из пушек по воробьям. Если не утилитой, то уж точно `perl` здесь более подходящий, как и его `cpan`. Если бы я знал конкретно, что делать, так и ответил бы, либо кинул бы другу чтобы он попытался.

Comment: @theoden: поставил новые метки, т.к. подозреваю, что в .NET должны быть библиотеки для обработки документов MS Office )

Answer (score 1):

На C# - поставить [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425), добавить референсы на DocumentFormat.OpenXml и WindowsBase, и почистить нужные свойства кодом:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

public static void CleanupMetadata(string path)
{
    using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true))
    {
        document.PackageProperties.Creator = null;
        document.PackageProperties.LastModifiedBy = null;    
    }
}
```

Если принципиально решение из шелла - код выше достаточно легко переписывается на powershell.